# Implement SHA1 algorithm in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, encryption

I am building an application in Flex, wherein I need to encrypt user id and password using the SHA1 alogorithm. I have not come across any standard Flex library which allows me to do this. Does anyone know how to achieve this in Flex?

Regards
Aparna

Comment: Be aware that using SHA1 to run the username and password through is not "encryption." SHA1 is a hash function and you will at minimum need to salt the data you are running through it.

Answer (score 3):

I rolled my own long ago in Haxe (starting from a C implementation) and could be trivial to convert that to AS. However seems that this is now easily available in this [SHA1 implementation in as3](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/SHA1.as?r=2) directly from corelib.

Comment: Beware that as implemented, com.adobe.crypto.SHA1 truncates the characters of the input string by using only the low 8 bits. I recommend modifying it to first put the input string into a ByteArray using `ByteArray.writeUTFBytes()` and then compute the hash on the resulting ByteArray.